# Create file with customizeable name [PHP]

Tags: php

I have this code, which will create result.png on my server:

```
imagepng($image, "'./result/result.png");
```

Now I have `$text` , `$type` , `$id`

How can I create file with result_`$text` _ `$id` _  `$type`?

Example: `./result/result_123_131_1.png` ; 
`./result/result_Text_1364_3.png`

Comment: First, you write some code.

Comment: It would be nice to see what it was that you tried in order to have resolved this yourself, which would have shown us that you did research this before posting the question. 
When you try, you also learn. If someone just gives you an answer/solution, it would have all been for nothing and I say this for the/your future. 
You can then edit your post to contain something that may have failed; even that shows an effort on your part. Remember, we're always glad to help :-)

Comment: With concatenation.

Comment: [so] is not a _free coding_ website. Please show us the effort you've put in and what you've tried so far. We're here to help when you run in to problems but **not** to write your code for you. I'd recommend you take the [tour] and read the [ask] page to learn how to ask a proper question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple:

```
$name = "./result/result_$text_$id_$type";
//do whatever you do to save the image and use $name as name of the file.
```

In php the double quotes are used whenever you have variables you want to use in some string literal. What I do above is I insert the value of the variables into the string literal `"./result/result___"`.
More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

Answer (score 0):

```
$image = imagepng($image, "'./result/result");    
$file = $image . "_" . $text . "_" . $id . "_" . $type ."png";
```